# How do I build this table?

Tags: tables

[image: table]

I tried with \multirowcell with limited success, since I am not sure how to create the long first column without a horizontal line going though it!

Here is what I have tied:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X }
\usepackage[autolanguage, np]{numprint}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll|rrr}
\hline
\multirowcell{10}{Paragraph 11) \\ Elections \&\\ Variables } & \multirowcell{4}{Base Currency \&\\ Eligible Currency}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{i) "Base Currency" means United States Dollars}} \\
 & & & &\\
 \cline{3-5}
 & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{i) "Eligible  Currency" means the Base Currency }} \\
  & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \\
 \hline
\multirowcell{6} & (B) Credit Support Obligations & & i) Delivery Amount, Return Amount \& Credit Support Amount & \\
 & & & A) "Delivery Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 2(a) & \\
 & & & B) "Return Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 2 (b) & \\
 & & & C) "Credit Support Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 10& \\
 & & & & \\
 \cline{1-5}
\multirowcell{6} & & A & USD cash in an Eligible Currency & \\
 &  & B & 40 & 36 \\
 & & C & 38 & 34 \\
 & & D & 31 & 37 \\
 & \makecell{Não concordo nem \\ discordo} &  & 25 & 27 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image]

UPDATE:
I got closer but now the lower right corner text does not line up.

```
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}\hline
\multirow{10}{*}{\parbox{2.0cm}{\raggedright Paragraph 11) Elections \& Variables}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\raggedright(A) Base Currency \& Eligible Currency}} & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{i) "Base Currency" means United States Dollars}     \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{ii) "Eligible Currency" Means the Base Currency}     \\ \cline{2-5}
                        & \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox{3.5cm}{\raggedright(B) Credit Support Obligations}} & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{\parbox{10.0cm}{\raggedright A) "Delivery Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 2(a)}}    \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{\parbox{10.0cm}{\raggedright B) "Return Amount" has the meaning specified in the Paragrah 2(b)}}      \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{\parbox{10.0cm}{\raggedright C) "Credit Support Amount" has the meaning specified in Paragraph 10}}    \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{\parbox{10.0cm}{\raggedright ii) Eligible Credit Support. The following items will qualify as 'Eligible Credit Support' for both Party A and Party B.}} \\ \cline{3-5}
                        &                        &   &               & Haircut  \\ \cline{3-5}
                        &                        & A & USD cash in an Eligible Currency            & 100\% \\
                        &                        & B & \parbox{8.0cm}{\raggedright Securities issued or directly \& fully guaranteed or insured by the Government of the USA having a maturity of less than 5 years from the Valuation Date}           & 100\% \\
                        &                        & C & \parbox{8.0cm}{\raggedright Securities issued or directly guaranteed or issued by the Government of the USA of more than 5 years but not more than 10 years from the Valuation Date}          & 98\% \\
                        &                        & D & \parbox{8.0cm}{\raggedright Securities issued or directly \& fully guaranteed by the Government of the USA having maturities of 10 years or more from the Valuation Date} & 95\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which produces this result:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried? A minimal working example (MWE) would be perfect ...

Comment: I am sorry the text is a little different.. but I want to have the nice long columns and the table not falling off the page!

Comment: It will be difficult to get the auto-numbering working.  What's the numbering scheme?  It's very hard to infer from your example.

Comment: Sorry the auto numbering is kind of random I can enter it per hand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this table via `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`:

[image]

For the case where the first column has longer text, I'd use a `\parbox` with `\raggedright`:

```
\multirow{10}{*}{\parbox{2.0cm}{\raggedright Test1 with some more text}}
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}\hline
\multirow{10}{*}{Test1} & \multirow{2}{*}{hello} & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{i) Now}     \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{ii) Is}     \\ \cline{2-5}
                        & \multirow{8}{*}{world} & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{A) Time}    \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{B) To}      \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{C) Stay}    \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{ii) Focused} \\ \cline{3-5}
                        &                        &   &               & Val  \\ \cline{3-5}
                        &                        & A & Or            & 99\% \\
                        &                        & B & You           & 98\% \\
                        &                        & C & Will          & 95\% \\
                        &                        & D & Fall as sleep & 93\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Longer Text in First Column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}\hline
\multirow{10}{*}{\parbox{2.0cm}{\raggedright Test1 with some more text}} & \multirow{2}{*}{hello} & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{i) Now} \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{ii) Is} \\ \cline{2-5}
                        & \multirow{8}{*}{world} & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{A) Time} \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{B) To} \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{C) Stay} \\
                        &                        & \multicolumn{3}{l |}{ii) Focused} \\ \cline{3-5}
                        &                        &   &               & Val \\ \cline{3-5}
                        &                        & A & Or            & 99\% \\
                        &                        & B & You           & 98\% \\
                        &                        & C & Will          & 95\% \\
                        &                        & D & Fall as sleep & 93\% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
If I make the text "Test1" longer can I make newlines in that column?

Comment: @Damian: Have updated solution for this.

Comment: You are star***